# restrict input if partial fields differ from other record

Tags: ms-access

I'm newbie in access so I need some help in a problem that I faced:
supposed I have table with 3 fields : id(unique), fname(first_name) and lname(last_name).

I want to be able that first name is somehow unique too, what I mean is that if lets say I have a record like this:
|ID| fname | lname
|00|    Ned   |   Stark

If I want to add Robb Stark error will raised because there is already a Stark **BUT** If I want to add again Ned Stark its Ok.

|ID| fname | lname
|00|    Ned   |   Stark
|01|    Ned   |   Stark           <--- That's ok

|ID| fname | lname
|00|    Ned   |   Stark
|01|    Robb  |   Stark           <--- That's not

Be grateful for your help :)

Comment: Why do you want to add Ned Stark twice?

Comment: Odd requirement. Write code to validate data. When you have specific issue, post question.